# I need hashtag sign in url launcher TEL, but it gets removed automatically

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to dial this number as it is, in flutter url launcher but it removes the hashtag sign in the last bit of the String,

```
 onTap: () {
                                String no = '*477*4*1#';
                                launch('tel:$no');
                              },
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Uri.encodeComponent('*477*4*1#');` 
code snippet

```
onPressed: () {
        String no = Uri.encodeComponent('*477*4*1#');
        launch('tel:$no');
      },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('click'),
              onPressed: () {
                String no = Uri.encodeComponent('*477*4*1#');
                launch('tel:$no');
              },
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL Encoding for special character so `#` is equals to `\%23`.